# How to programmatically determine the Outlook New Item created from Home Ribbon --> New Items

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I have a Outlook Add-in which is a new Ribbon tab which connects to my server database for some custom data to be associated with an Outlook Object.

This ribbon tab shows in Mail Item as of now.

I am extending it to show in Tasks and Calendar items (*Appointment, Meeting etc*).

Currently the way I am determining the new item created is as follows -->

```cs
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application interopApplication = ThisAddIn.Application.Application
if (interopApplication.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder.DefaultItemType.ToString() != "olTaskItem")
{
  ....
}
```

This way I am able to determine the folder and its associated new item (*like in Inbox, I create New Mail Item, in Calendar I create new Appointment etc*)

Now when I am in Inbox, and I click on New Appointment, it identifies the new item created as `olMailItem` and not as `olAppointmentItem`. Same is the case when I am in Calendar view and I click on New Mail Item.

My Question is how do I determine the new item created irrespective from which folder I am in?

Answer (score 1):

You should check the [`MessageClass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861573.aspx) of the [`ActiveInspector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863939.aspx) method to determine the `OlItemType`.

```cs
string itemClass = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem.MessageClass;
if (itemClass == "IPM.Appointment")
  // you have a calendar item
else if (itemClass == "IPM.Task")
  // you have a task item
else if (itemClass == "IPM.Note")
  // you have a message item
```

Comment: @SilverNinja : Thanks for the information. However i could not get the MessageClass of the CurrentItem Directly as mentioned above. I used the following Link to get the Message class From StackOverflow [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171357/outlook-2010-addin-behaves-weirdly-when-mail-invoked-from-other-office-client/13697970#13697970)